# Ffmpeg concat Audio synch do not work with mp4 videos in C#.Net

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

I am trying A.mp4,B.mp4,C.mp4 files to be concated in sequence into D.mp4.

I tried variety of concat commands but its not working well, and audio , video are not synch.
Also D.mp4 is going large in size and time.

Pls provide a sample that can work on c#.Net. My code is

```
string c1 = " -i " + video1 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t1;// +" && ";
string c2 = " -i " + video2 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t2;// + " && ";
string c3 = " -i " + video3 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t3;// + " && ";
string ct = " -i \"concat:" + t1+ "|"+t2+ "|" +t3+"\" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "+strResult;
```

Thanks in Advance
Bhupendra

Comment: Pls provide a sample that u tried on c#.Net.

Comment: @CaiusJard   I am using below commands -                                                                  string c1 = " -i " + video1 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t1;// +" && ";
string c2 = " -i " + video2 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t2;// + " && ";
string c3 = " -i " + video3 + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + t3;// + " && ";
string ct = " -i \"concat:" + t1+ "|"+t2+ "|" +t3+"\" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "+strResult;